# why my animation of setAlpha stop the button receive sender?

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, alpha

I want to get a flicker button , and then I code like this
I init the button like this:

```
_btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
[_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the I code the animation like this :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    _btn.alpha = 0.2;
} completion:nil];
```

The button is vague but it can not be selected , it can not receive the sender .
Anyone knows why it can not receive the sender ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    _btn.alpha = 0.2;
} completion:nil];
```

I have inserted this in the above code as options

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

Answer (score 1):

I don`t know why it can`t receive the sender , maybe because of the alpha is changing all the time . but I have a way to solve it . you can creat a background button , it can receive the sender , you can code like this :

```
    _btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    _btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [_btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    _btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
    [_btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_btn1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_btn1 addSubView : _btn];
```

and then set the animation like your code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    _btn.alpha = 0.2;
} completion:nil];
```

the button1 will receive the sender

Comment: thank you very much , it can work too , but I think Pranjal`s answer is better.